# NHibernate select query

Tags: .net, linq, nhibernate

I have the following problem:

```
public IList<Category> GetLeafCategories()
{
    // select all categories that are not ParentCategory
    string sqlQuery =  @"
    select * from Catalog_Categories c
    where c.CategoryId not in (
        select distinct ParentCategoryId 
        from Catalog_Categories)
    ";

    //
    // I need an equivalent nHibernate query
    //
    var categs = NHibernateSession.Current.Query<Category>();
    IQueryable<Category> leafCategs = from cat in categs
                                      where cat.Id not in // HOW TO???
                                          (from c in categs 
                                           select c.ParentCategory.Id)
                                        select cat;
    return leafCategs.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Im not tested this, but it should work:

```
var session = NHibernateSession.Current;

var subquery = session.Query<Category>
    .Select(x => x.ParentCategory.Id);

return session.Query<Category>
    .Where(x => !subquery.Contains(x.Id))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This seems to be a brilliant answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
var categs = NHibernateSession.Current.Query<Category>();
IQueryable<Category> leafCategs = from cat in categs
                                  let parentIds = 
                                      (from c in categs 
                                       select c.ParentCategory.Id)
                                  where !parentIds.Any( p => p == cat.Id)
                                 select cat;
```

You can do it like above.